# Where is SNR and CNR calculated for LTE?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, lte

I read below that SNR and CNR are different and we have difference of post/pre modulation.
In context of LTE which modulation do we refer to- Digital Data **modulated** using QAM/QPSK to IQ, or Baseband **modulation** to Passband/RF?

https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/Carrier_to_Noise_Ratio_versus_Signal_to_Noise_Ratio.html

Comment: well, I'm really not sure what exactly a carrier is in an OFDM system. Could you elaborate? (long story short: the distinction between SNR and C/N is not really useful here. You'd tend to care more about SNR when building a receiver)

Comment: http://teletopix.org/4g-lte/what-is-carrier-to-interference-plus-noise-ratio-in-lte/ I read here, honesty I'm not sure about clear distinction, that's why wanted to explore more.

Comment: yes, that's just another resource saying "it's the ratio of power between the carrier and...", and I'll honestly say, "carrier" isn't really a well-defined word in the context of OFDM. You ask "where is SNR and where CNR calculated for LTE" and the answer is "LTE itself uses neither metric, because they're not that useful".

Comment: again "where is it calculated": LTE doesn't use that measure in itself, so you're totally free to define it however you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining this.

Comment: Notice that LTE's OFDM (or SC-FDM) is really an equalizing system, so, by the very problem it's solving implies that the overall power of anything isn't really very useful. Different subcarriers will be attenuated differently – that's the whole point.