# How is SNR Calculated in OFDM Reciever?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, lte

Can you please guide me on the information to calculate SNR for OFDM Reciever?
Is OFDM Pilots used for it? And do we need to follow channel estimation like steps of interpolation to determine it?
I'm a little confused and where do we calculate it- Baseband Analog or Baseband Digital portion.
Please point me to answers if already given specific to this question.

Already asked somewhat similar question before [Where is SNR and CNR calculated for LTE?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79060/where-is-snr-and-cnr-calculated-for-lte)  and this is an addition/more detailed question to it.

Comment: hm, a single SNR for a complete OFDM signal seems to be a bad idea. The total SNR tells you nothing about how good your signal is – channel capacity is not linear, so how the signal- and noise energy is distributed across the subcarriers is important, and cannot be represented by a single number. Other than that, SNR is always calculated the same: signal power divided by noise power. And as Dilip says, how you estimate these is up to your individual application and needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are quite broad and hence difficult to answer. If the communication system can afford the bandwidth for a pilot signal, then a pilot can be used. Yes, channel estimation would be needed. Typically, SNRs would be calculated in the digital domain.

However, these answers won't help you and you'll need to delve into the theory more deeply. If you want to understand the theory, I'd recommend reading a textbook like [this one](https://www.google.com/books/edition/OFDM_Systems_for_Wireless_Communications/ZrJQe4hjQzYC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Disclaimer: I haven't actually read this book and there may be other better ones. However, a quick scan suggests that it addresses the question of SNR estimation.